# How to get the spent time in the multithreaded application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, time, cross-platform

How can I get the spent time in multithreading application?
I used `clock()`, `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`, `QElapsedTimer`.
All of them works well in Windows. But in Linux the result is several times more than it is.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you use `steady_clock`? Not tested but `system_clock` should work.

Comment: I'm just trying to find the solution how to count the time between the start and the end of function independently of the threads count.

Comment: @YiFei Why you think system clock should work fine

Comment: @Kapil, system_clock corresponds to "wall clock", while steady_clock corresponds to something more like a monotonic program counter that has no physical meaning.

Comment: What do you mean by "several times more than it is"? Need a code example to understand. I assure you that there are no problems with `system_clock` or `steady_clock` on Linux.

Comment: If two threads start now and work 10 seconds each, it doesn't mean the overall time is twenty seconds - it's still 10 seconds.

Comment: Are you looking for accurate CPU time?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in a portable way

```
high_resolution_clock::time_point start = high_resolution_clock::now();
function();

auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(
 high_resolution_clock::now() - t1 ).count();
```